# When I multiply the numbers by each other in an array I am getting a negative number. How do I correct this?

Tags: java, arrays, product

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    int A[]={2,4,6,9,5,4,5,7,12,15,21,32,45,5,6,7,12};
    int multi= 1;
    for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        multi *= A[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The product of the numbers in the array is " + multi );
    //I keep getting a negative value but when I shorten the array
    //to a few numbers I don't have any problems.
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow; relevant xkcd: http://xkcd.com/571/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's called *overflow*.

> An integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic operation attempts to create a numeric value that is too large to be represented within the available storage space. [[Wikipedia - Integer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)]

`int`s can represent a maximum of `(2^32)-1`. Your multiplication gives a result that is higher than that value, so it generates overflow.

Change `multi` type to `long` and you won't have this problem (but only for that particular case: if you exceed the maximum value representable by a `long`, you'll have that problem again)

---

As said, changing the type to `long` will only *postpone* the problem, you can solve it by using a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), which can handle arbitrary-precision integers.

**But** use it only if you really have to. If you know that your app will do calculations without exceeding the `long` max representable value, then use a `long`, as the `BigInteger` is not a primitive and will be much slower than a `long`.

Comment: You'll still have this problem, but higher numbers are representable.
I'd suggest 2 things to increase the max representable number, first as stated above, change type to long, then as is product, you can count the number of negatives, and use that as to determine output sign. Then save numbers as unsigned long (you can represent twice as many positive numbers now), then when printing you print sign value.

Comment: @NullUserException Didn't I write about it?

Comment: @Sinn Java doesn't support `usigned` types by default

Comment: But Java does have the capability to handle [arbitrary-precision integers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: @NullUserException Yes. But a `BigInteger` is a lot slower than a primitive. You shouldn't use it if you don't really need it. For this type of calculations a `long` is enough. Anyway I'm writing about it as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Start by declaring `multi` as a `long`. When a value exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE i 'overflows' and becomes negative. The maximum integer value is just more than 2 billion, so it happens quite soon.

Answer (score 0):

You encounter a negative value, it is because the multi value exceeds the Max value of Integer (2^31 -1).

You need to make the change as follows:

From

```
int multi= 1;
```

To

```
long multi= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    int A[]={2,4,6,9,5,4,5,7,12,15,21,32,45,5,6,7,12};
    long multi= 1;
    for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        multi *= A[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The product of the numbers in the array is " + multi );
    //I keep getting a negative value but when I shorten the array
    //to a few numbers I don't have any problems.
}
```